# How can I change a jailbreak iPhone's UUID,SerialNumber,IMEI,ECID via code

Tags: objective-c, iphone, macos, itunes, jailbreak

Recently I got a job to imitate a Mac software that can change a jailbreak iPhone's UUID, SerialNumber, IMEI, ECID... I tried to decompile it but eventually failed.

Now I can get an iPhone's device info through iTunes lib, but I can't modify it. Are there any good ideas to modify a jailbreak iPhone's device information?

Comment: On what level do you intend to modify that data? Because e.g. the ECID is burned into the chip...

Comment: Probably be able to deceive iTunes，I think it‘s enough.

Comment: If you want to send iTunes fake data then just install hooks in daemons that deal with USB communication. For example, lockdownd. iTunes doesn't read data directly, it asks for it from daemons running on the device.

Comment: @creker Thanks for your help, I observed that after using the software to modify the information, the modified iPhone's settings--general-about has become modified information.Maybe it changed in deeper level?The other things I found is after modify it required reboot and activate iPhone.